# iText signing PDF using external signature with smart card

Tags: pdf, itext, digital-signature, smartcard, itextpdf

I've been toying with iTextSharp 5.5.7 for a while and can't find the right way to make a valid digital signature for PDF from Smart Card - Adobe Reader always says its signed by and unknown and can't decode signatures' DER data.

I've looked at [MakeSignature.cs](http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/itextsharp/ci/b11cad134c1a0572ea8322330ce49321c584b010/tree/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/security/MakeSignature.cs) code for reference and what is does:

```
        Stream data = signatureAppearance.GetRangeStream(); 
        // gets the first hash
        byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, hashAlgorithm);
        // gets the second hash or is it not a hash at all ?
        byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, ocsp, crlBytes, sigtype);
```

then, according to "sign" method in [IExternalSignature.cs](https://github.com/itext/itextsharp/blob/master/src/core/iTextSharp/text/pdf/security/IExternalSignature.cs)

> "@param message   the message you want to be hashed and signed"

```
        // looks like externalSignature.Sign() should make another hash out of "sh"
        // and use this hash to compute a signature
        byte[] extSignature = externalSignature.Sign(sh);
```

so I understood the procedure of signing as the following:

1. source PDF is loaded
2. new PDF with empty signature field is created
3. Byte range of that field is hashed (by default produces 20 bytes for sha-1, tried 32 bytes with sha-256 too)
4. that Hash + some other properties are hashed again (number of bytes
   varies, why? might not be a hash after all?)
5. that second hash is hashed again inside of external signature object
6. that third hash is finally sent to a Smart Card to compute a
   signature
7. Signature is inserted into new PDF

When i sign PDF with Adobe Reader, at step 6, the third hash is 32 bytes long.
From Smart Card's perspective i do the same steps with both Acrobat and iText, but with iText the signature is invalid, what could be wrong ?

---

the code i use:

```
public void StartTest(){
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
        cert.Import("cert.cer"); // certificate obtained from smart card

        X509CertificateParser certParse = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();

        Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { certParse.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData) };

        // Reader and stamper
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader("original.pdf");
        Stream signedPdf = new FileStream("signed.pdf", FileMode.Create);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(pdfReader, signedPdf, '\0', null, false);

        // Appearance
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
        appearance.SignatureCreator = "Me";
        appearance.Reason = "Testing iText";
        appearance.Location = "On my Laptop";
        appearance.SignatureGraphic = Image.GetInstance("img.png"); // visual image
        appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(50, 50, 250, 100), pdfReader.NumberOfPages, "Signature");
        appearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.GRAPHIC_AND_DESCRIPTION;

        // Timestamp
        TSAClientBouncyCastle tsc = new TSAClientBouncyCastle("http://ts.cartaodecidadao.pt/tsa/server", "", "");

        // Digital signature
        IExternalSignature externalSignature = new MyExternalSignature2("SHA-1");
        MyMakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, externalSignature, chain, null, null, tsc, 0, CryptoStandard.CADES);

        stamper.Close();
}
```

external signature implementation (class MyExternalSignature2):

```
    class MyExternalSignature2 : IExternalSignature
{
    private String hashAlgorithm;
    private String encryptionAlgorithm;

    public MyExternalSignature2(String hashAlgorithm)
    {
        this.encryptionAlgorithm = "RSA";
        this.hashAlgorithm = DigestAlgorithms.GetDigest(DigestAlgorithms.GetAllowedDigests(hashAlgorithm));
    }

    public virtual byte[] Sign(byte[] message) {

        byte[] hash = null;
        using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            hash = sha1.ComputeHash(message);
        }

        byte[] sig = MySC.GetSignature(hash);

        return sig;
    }

    public virtual String GetHashAlgorithm() {
        return hashAlgorithm;
    }

    public virtual String GetEncryptionAlgorithm() {
        return encryptionAlgorithm;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try with `X509Certificate2Signature`? It gets the certificates from the windows certificate store (the certificates should appear ther when you insert the card) and lets the smartcard middleware do all the work.

Comment: @PauloSoares unfortunately i cannot use official middleware, i did my own to support ios. It can get certificates and do the nesessary crypto. I even emulated the same transactions of bytes by Adobe Reader using my driver and iText but it produces invalid signature, though certificate and other stuff are there

Comment: *that second hash is hashed again inside of external signature object* - that is too often. The document byte ranges are hashed, this value is added to the so-called signed attributes which indeed then are signed which includes an additional hashing. Three consecutive hashings are one too many.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The OP supplied a number of sample signed documents, and analyzing them it became obvious that my initial answer was based on a misunderstanding.*

### Analysis of supplied signed PDFs

The OP supplied three PDFs signed by his code, at first these two:

- [ex_signed.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/00gpsg31nsw3ydt/ex_signed.pdf?dl=0) (signed with sha-1 and CryptoStandard.CADES)
- [ex_signed_2.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uz38qqvxejyyve0/ex_signed_2.pdf?dl=0) (signed with sha-1 and CryptoStandard.CADES)

Inspecting them a peculiarity of iText CAdES signing with SHA1 became appearant: for `CryptoStandard.CADES` iText uses the `SigningCertificateV2` attribute even for SHA1 but specifications recommend using the `SigningCertificate` attribute there instead. To prevent this peculiarity from interfering, the OP supplied the third file

- [ex_signed_3.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhydbfjaejthhnl/ex_signed_3.pdf?dl=0) (signed with sha-256 and CryptoStandard.CMS)

It turned out, though, that this quirk was not the cause of the OP's observations, Adobe Reader still reports cryptography library errors.

Thus, back to analysis.

As the signature algorithms were SHA1withRSA/2048 and SHA256withRSA/2048, one can simply decrypt the inner signature value using the public key from the respective certificate.

This succeeded for ex_signed.pdf but not for ex_signed_2.pdf or ex_signed_3.pdf.

The OP meanwhile indicated in a comment:

> the difference between those files are certificates used for signatures, in the first i used a certificate for authentication, which is (i think is) acceptable but i have another certificate specifically for digital signatures, which i used in 2nd and 3rd file.

So I tried to decode the signature value in the second and third file using the certificate from the first file, and indeed, that worked! So the second and third file claim to be signed by the private key associated with that alternative certificate but actually are signed using the private key associated with the former certificate.

Thus: **Problem 1: Signatures in files 2 and 3 are signed with the wrong private key / the wrong application on the smart card.**

To further analyze the issue, I looked at the signature values successfully decoded with the authentication certificate:

- ex_signed.pdf:

  ```
    2a8945abe450b2c1cd232249b8f811d352ad0d29
  ```
- ex_signed_2.pdf

  ```
    cc24acc848002df63733941e34437f8aef1c746c
  ```
- ex_signed_3.pdf

  ```
    45f8e451f8b9f39f0c1f59eea8b6308fba22176ac62ebd14bbf07e5407aed7e8
  ```

So for SHA1 there are 20 bytes and for SHA-256 there are 32 bytes. This is exactly the size of the hash values, so most likely these simply are the naked hash values.

This is wrong, though, XXXwithRSA signatures are expected to contain an encrypted structure which contains an OID of the hashing algorithm and the hash, in ASN.1 notation:

```
DigestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
  digestAlgorithm DigestAlgorithmIdentifier, 
  digest Digest
  }

DigestAlgorithmIdentifier ::= AlgorithmIdentifier

Digest ::= OCTET STRING
```

For backgrounds cf. [RFC 3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447).

This explains the OP's observation:

> the error in the first is described as "BER decoding error",

The verifier tries to interpret the naked hash as an ASN.1 sequence encoded using the BER which obviously fails.

Thus: **Problem 2: The smart card encrypts the naked hash value but has to encrypt a `DigestInfo` object encapsulating that hash.**

### Initial, obsolete answer

If your `MySC.GetSignature` call hashes while signing the data (and does not expect data to be already hashed before), you should replace

```
public virtual byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
{
    byte[] hash = null;
    using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        hash = sha1.ComputeHash(message);
    }

    byte[] sig = MySC.GetSignature(hash);

    return sig;
}
```

by something like

```
public virtual byte[] Sign(byte[] message)
{
    byte[] sig = MySC.GetSignature(message);

    return sig;
}
```

Comment: according to ISO 7816-8, smart card can accept hash value (without hashing received data) following by compute signature command and looking at what Adobe Reader does, it likely seems to do exactly that, it sends 32 bytes of hash and receives 256 bytes of signature. So it must be something else

Comment: The answer is based on your question where you essentially say that there are three digests, the latter two calculated from the respectively previous one. That is one hashing iteration too many, so my answer removed the obvious candidate iteration. If you have already tried that and it didn't work, you have yet another problem which the information you provided fail to show. Thus, please lay out your use case in more detail.

Comment: You might share a document signed with your code for analysis.

Comment: you can download from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/00gpsg31nsw3ydt/ex_signed.pdf?dl=0 check updated question, regarding "Sign" method. @mkl

Comment: [here is another PDF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uz38qqvxejyyve0/ex_signed_2.pdf?dl=0), now it shows 0x2726 "crypto library error"

Comment: I'll have a look at the files as soon as I'm at a computer again, currently I'm on my smart phone.

Comment: Looking at your sample PDFs I saw a peculiarity of iText CAdES signing with SHA1 (iText uses the SigningCertificateV2 attribute even for SHA1 which is not recommended). Thus, could you try to switch to a more advanced hashing algorithm, e.g. SHA-256, or test again with CryptoStandard.CMS instead of CryptoStandard.CADES (the attribute only is used for CAdES)? I'm not sure whether that helps but that inappropriate attribute might cause some trouble. When I'm back in office next week, I can look into the signature more deeply.

Comment: Can you share a sample?

Comment: [sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhydbfjaejthhnl/ex_signed_3.pdf?dl=0) signed with sha-256 and CryptoStandard.CMS, @mkl

Comment: @YaroslavAlexeevich I finally got to look at the internals of your signatures. Actually it looks like the first attempt (in ex_signed.pdf) is the one to go back to and to improved: Only the first one actually used the correct private key for RSA encryption (what have you changed for #2 and #3?).

Comment: @YaroslavAlexeevich Unfortunately your `MySC.GetSignature` call actually merely encrypts the given data, not as I understodd you encrypts a hash of them. Thus, ignore my answer above.

Comment: @YaroslavAlexeevich What you need to have encrypted by your card, though, is not the plain hash you calculate but a structure which contains an OID of the hashing algorithm and the hash, in ASN.1 notation: `DigestInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
     digestAlgorithm DigestAlgorithmIdentifier,
     digest Digest }`

Comment: For details cf. [RFC 2313](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2313) / [RFC 2437](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2437) / [RFC 3447](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3447)

Comment: i tested your suggestion with no luck:                         byte[] hash = null;
            using (SHA256CryptoServiceProvider sha256 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                AsnEncodedData asnVal = new AsnEncodedData(new Oid("2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1"), message);
                hash = sha256.ComputeHash(asnVal.RawData);
            }

Comment: As mentioned above, there was something more correct in the first file than in the second or third. Have you based your new effort on the code that produced the first file?

Comment: the difference between those files are certificates used for signatures, in the first i used a certificate for authentication, which is (i think is) acceptable but i have another certificate specifically for digital signatures, which i used in 2nd and 3rd file. the error in the first is described as "BER decoding error", in the following files is "0x2726 crypto library error". i have no clue what is wrong, the PDFs content bytes are decodable. @mkl

Comment: the above code is a bit wrong, though makes no difference, the right is:              byte[] hash = null;
            using (SHA1CryptoServiceProvider sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                hash = sha1.ComputeHash(message);
                AsnEncodedData asnVal = new AsnEncodedData(new Oid("1.3.14.3.2.26"), hash);
                MySmartCard.Encrypt(asnVal.RawData);
            }

Comment: Ok. I'm currently editing the answer to give some details but concerning: *the difference between those files are certificates* - You include different certificates but still sign using the private key associated with the first certificate. Thus, file 2 and 3 have signature values which cannot successfully be interpreted in the context of the given certificate at all.

Comment: Concerning the ASN.1 classes: I don't know them and therefore cannot say whether they do their job correctly.

Comment: big thanks for the guidance, i ended up using the certificate issued by a certifier of authentication, instead of (the logical choice) the other certificate issued by certifier of digital signature and the proper key reference. though, looks strange that, the latter's subject is non-repudiation and the former's subject is digital signatures (very inconvenient issuer names)... and hardcoded Asn1 tags. i will update the question later. @mkl

Comment: According to [RFC 5280](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3) digitalSignature is used for digital signatures such as those used in an
      entity authentication service, a data origin authentication
      service, and/or an integrity service. And...

Comment: ... nonRepudiation is
      used for digital signatures used to provide a non-
      repudiation service that protects against the signing entity
      falsely denying some action.  In the case of later conflict, a
      reliable third party may determine the authenticity of the signed
      data.  (Note that recent editions of X.509 have renamed the
      nonRepudiation bit to contentCommitment.)